# The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

can anyone help me I am trying to make a circular percent indicator for battery percentage but I am getting this error, this for my college project work, and writing this post for the first time I have never done this before and I am also new at coding.

**lib/pages/device_dashboard.dart:139:36: Error: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.
percent: _batteryLevel,
^**

here is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:battery/battery.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeviceDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeviceDashboardState createState() => _DeviceDashboardState();
}

class _DeviceDashboardState extends State<DeviceDashboard> {
  Battery _battery = Battery();
  BatteryState _batteryState;

  int _batteryLevel;

  StreamSubscription<BatteryState> _batteryStateSubscription;
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _batteryStateSubscription =
        _battery.onBatteryStateChanged.listen((BatteryState state) {
      setState(() {
        _batteryState = state;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getLevel() async {
    final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    if (_batteryStateSubscription != null) {
      _batteryStateSubscription.cancel();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Device Dashboard'),
        ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Text(
              '$_batteryState',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.grey[400],
              ),
            ),

            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                CircularPercentIndicator(
                  radius: 100.0,
                  lineWidth: 7.0,
                  center: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: _getLevel,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      '$_batteryLevel %',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  progressColor: Colors.green,
                  percent: 0.5, // after putting _batteryLevel here i m getting that error 
                ),
                Text(
                  'Battery',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ketan Ramteke's answer is correct if you want to show decimal values to the user.
If this is not what you want, you may leave the variable int (as you currently have it) and just round the battery double level so it's int instead of double, you should't be getting this error anymore:

```
Future<void> _getLevel() async {
final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
setState(() {
  _batteryLevel = batteryLevel.round();
});
```

}

Comment: Ketan Ramteke, not working, even after changing `double _batteryLevel; //<= declare it as a double instead of int
//....
Future<void> _getLevel() async {
    final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;

    });
  }`   but now its showing me different error **The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building DeviceDashboard(dirty, state: _DeviceDashboardState#bfe3e):
The method '<' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: <(0.0)**

Comment: Luis Utrera, now working again, `Future<void> _getLevel() async {
    final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel.round();

    });
  }` but getting same error **The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building DeviceDashboard(dirty, state: _DeviceDashboardState#bfe3e): The method '<' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: <(0.0)**

Comment: not working even after i change, `double _batteryLevel; Future<void> _getLevel() async {
    final batteryLevel = await _battery.batteryLevel;
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel.roundToDouble();

    });
  }, or _batteryLevel = batteryLevel as double; `

Comment: and  `percent: 0.5, //this only should be between 0.0 to 1.0